# undefined symbol when loading custom rviz panel

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have some question when i write a panel for Rviz, when i add a extra .h file for my project. After **CATKIN_MAKE** with **no Error**, when i add it in Rviz, it show me this :

```
PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'Tiffer' failed to load.  Error: Failed to load library /home/tiffer/tiffer-catkin/devel/lib/libtiffer_panel.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/tiffer/tiffer-catkin/devel/lib/libtiffer_panel.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12tiffer_panel18CruiseLocationTool12onInitializeEv)
```

But I had add it in cpp, I use Kinetic under Ubuntu 16.04.

When I remove this .h file from my project, my panel works well again. Can someone tell my what's wrong with it?

Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef TIFFER_CRUISELOCATION_H
#define TIFFER_CRUISELOCATION_H

#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "rviz/default_plugin/tools/pose_tool.h"

#endif

#include <QObject>
#include <QInputDialog>

using namespace rviz;

namespace tiffer_panel
{
    class Arrow;
    class DisplayContext;
    class StringProperty;

    class CruiseLocationTool : public PoseTool
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
            CruiseLocationTool();
            virtual void onInitialize();
    
        protected:
            virtual void onPoseSet(double x, double y, double theta);
    
        private Q_SLOTS:
            void updateTopic();
    
        private:
            ros::NodeHandle nh_;
            ros::Publisher pub_;
    };    
}
#endif
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289918/undefined-symbol-when-loading-custom-rviz-panel/) by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the error:

```
Poco exception = /home/tiffer/tiffer-catkin/devel/lib/libtiffer_panel.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12tiffer_panel18CruiseLocationTool12onInitializeEv
```

It looks like you declare `onInitialize()` but never define it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-04-27**:
Thanks, I have solve it

**Comment by [Wilkson](https://answers.ros.org/users/52686/wilkson/) on 2020-04-15**:
Had a similar issue and solved with the same solution!